# Form submission with a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic

I am constructing a web page in classic ASP which has up to 10 links wrapped in forms and controlled by CSS to give a rollover and the appearance of a coloured block. When the block/link is clicked I need to download a Zip file to the user and at the same time submit the form back to itself so that a database can be updated with this information. The page would then be available for the next download by the user.

I can download the zip file to a new window but the form submits inconsistantly, perhaps you could advise. I have searched the web for a couple of weeks and not found an answer.

Each link is constructed as below

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="250" border="0">
     <form action="<%=request("script_name")%>" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
          <tr style="height:18px;" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
               <td bgcolor="#e6e6e6" align="center">
                    <a href="http://.....URL of Zip file" onClick="javascript:document.forms(0).submit();" class="dload">DOWNLOAD</a> 
                    <input type="Hidden" name="trak" value="1">
               </td>
          </tr>
     </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Eeek. Invalid HTML. Presentational HTML. Trying to use `document.forms` as a function. I'd strongly suggest going back to the basics, there is a lot wrong here. http://wsc.opera.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementById("form1").submit()` would be slightly more robust than assuming this form will always be the first in the document. I think it's slightly more cross-browser compatible, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://.....URL of Zip file" 
     onClick="javascript:window.open(this.href); document.forms[0].submit();return false;" class="dload">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about forms. You are doing logging, that is not a significant change on the server. Switch the ASP to expect GET instead of POST then just do:

```
<a href="<%=request("script_name")%>?trak=1">...</a>
```

And have the logging script return the zip file (either by reading the data and returning it directly or responding with a 302 redirect).

Don't try to get the browser to make two HTTP requests for one link, that way just leads to a nasty mess.